# ASP.NET MVC3 DropDownListFor Enum

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

Hi I'm fairly new to MVC3 and I'm trying to do something that I think must be fairly common, but can't quite get it.

I have a model I wish store the value for enum DayOfWeek in:

```
public class Booking
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int Day { get; set; }
    ....
}
```

I've made it an int to store in the database.

I want to edit in the View as a DropDownList:

```
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Booking.Day, new SelectList(Enum.GetValues(typeof(DayOfWeek))))
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Booking.Day)
    </div>
```

However I get the error: "The field day must be a number".

I know I'm missing something, and probably something simple, can anyone help?

Comment: What is the value of mode.Booking.Day at that point in the code? Is it a number? or is it null? or something else?

Comment: As far as I can tell, it's the string of the enum. ie: Monday

Comment: Isn't model.Booking.Day an int? "public int Day { get; set; }"

Comment: Yes, and that's why I'm getting the error. I want to choose the day from the drop down and return the enum value, rather than the string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a SelectList property to your viewmodel and populate as per @Brandon's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1110070/how-to-get-the-values-of-an-enum-into-a-selectlist).

Then you will change your code to:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Booking.Day, Model.SelectListProperty)
```

(where `SelectListProperty` is the name of your property on your viewmodel)

Answer (score 0):

You can also change your model class using DayOfWeek:

```
public class Booking
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public DayOfWeek Day { get; set; }
}
```