# enumeration toselectlist with correct value

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, enums

USing ASPNET MVC 4, Say i have an enum

```
public enum IndicatorGroup
    {
        Include_ANY_MatchingIndicator = 1,
        Include_ALL_MatchingIndicator = 2,
        Exclude_ANY_MatchingIndicator = 3,
        Exclude_ALL_MatchingIndicator = 4
    };
```

I use the following helper method to bind it to drop down list as described here: [How do you create a dropdownlist from an enum in ASP.NET MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388483/how-do-you-create-a-dropdownlist-from-an-enum-in-asp-net-mvc)

```
public static class MyExtensions{
    public static SelectList ToSelectList<TEnum>(this TEnum enumObj)
        where TEnum : struct, IComparable, IFormattable, IConvertible
    {
        var values = from TEnum e in Enum.GetValues(typeof(TEnum))
            select new { Id = e, Name = e.ToString() };
        return new SelectList(values, "Id", "Name", enumObj);
    }
}
```

Now i want that the selected value is a number (this is probably specified in the above code as)

```
Id = e ,
```

but when i get the selected value it returns me the text Exclude_ALL_MatchingIndicator instead of the number 4. How do i set it properly?

**VIEW**

```
 @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.IndicatorGroups, Model.IndicatorGroups.ToSelectList(), new { @id = "ddlIndicatorGroup" })
```

Comment: `Id = (int)e`, but why do you want it to be a number?

Comment: did id = (int)e but it gave parse error. cannot convert type TEnum to int

Comment: i simply want to set value in dropdown list as the numbers and text as Include_ANY_MatchingIndicator etc

Comment: similar question is here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1110070/how-to-get-the-values-of-an-enum-into-a-selectlist

Comment: Use `Id = Convert.ToInt32(e)`

Comment: But still not clear why you want it to be a number. To generate your dropdownlist in the view, it should be `@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.IndicatorGroups. Model.IndicatorGroups.ToSelectList())` and if the value of  `IndicatorGroups ` is `Include_ALL_MatchingIndicator ` then the 2nd option will be selected.

Comment: Cool it works! you can add the answer.. i am passing this number to my stored procedure..Are you saying this is not the best practice?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139317/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-samra).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Convert.ToInt32(e)`, so that the code becomes

```
var values = from TEnum e in Enum.GetValues(typeof(TEnum))
             select new { Id = Convert.ToInt32(e), Name = e.ToString() };
return new SelectList(values, "Id", "Name", Convert.ToInt32(enumObj));
```

However, you do not really want to do that. If the value of property `IndicatorGroups` is say `IndicatorGroup.Exclude_ANY_MatchingIndicator`, then your `DropDownListFor()` method will initially display the first option because the value of the property does not match any of the option values. Internally, the method builds a new `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` based on the 2nd parameter, and sets the `Selected` property if the `.ToString()` value of the property matches the `Value` property of any `SelectListItem` - in your case `"Exclude_ANY_MatchingIndicator"` will not match `1`, `2`, `3`, or `4` so the first option will be selected (because something has to be).

You have indicated in the comments that you want to save the selected value as an`INT` in the database, in which case, in your POST method, convert the bound value to an `int`. Assuming you select the 2nd option in the view, then the `IndicatorGroups` property of your model will be `IndicatorGroup.Include_ALL_MatchingIndicator`. To save the value as an `int`, use

```
int valueToSave = (int)model.IndicatorGroups; // returns 2
```