# Html.GetEnumSelectList and pre selected values (edit page)

Tags: c#, enums, dropdown

```
    public enum PageType
    {
        [Display(Name = "Brak")]
        None = 0,
        [Display(Name = "Strona")]
        Page = 1,
        [Display(Name = "Sklep")]
        Shop = 2,
        [Display(Name = "Error")]
        Error = 3
    }
```

View model - `ValueTypeEditViewModel` containes `ValueTypeModel` which have `Conroller` (`string`)

for dropdown I'm using:

```
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="ValueType.Controller" class="m-1"></label>
            <div><span asp-validation-for="ValueType.Controller" class="text-danger"></span></div>
            <select class="custom-select" asp-for="ValueType.Controller" asp-items="Html.GetEnumSelectList<ValueTypeModel.PageType>()"></select>
        </div>
```

Which generate perfectly a dropdown, but when I edit page earlier selected `Value Type.Controller` does not select. Before I save value I have to do some logic with value wchich is a number (string) to transfer it to name and save word. This work like I select `[Display(Name = "Strona")] Page = 1,` then the `Value Type.Controller` is a string `1` and I have to lookup for name and save to db `Page`

**Question** how to render dropdown with earlier selected value

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense for `ValueType.Controller` to be of type `ValueTypeModel.PageType` instead of `string`?

Comment: @DavidG in other situations, values other than those from the enum are stored there

Comment: Then you have a serious problem with your code. Properties shouldn't be multipurpose, that is a nasty code smell.

Comment: `to be of type ValueTypeModel.PageType` is this the reason that the previously selected options are not selected? In total, I never created `propertie` with `type of enum` just `int`. Those enums with `int prop` are selected well

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74559116/7186739

Answer (score 1):

this is not really the full answer - just **nasty fix** the problem

```
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="ValueType.Controller" class="m-1"></label>
        <div><span asp-validation-for="ValueType.Controller" class="text-danger"></span></div>
        <select class="custom-select" asp-for="ValueType.Controller">
            @foreach (var e in Enum.GetValues(typeof(ValueTypeModel.PageType)).Cast<int>())
            {
                if (Enum.GetName(typeof(ValueTypeModel.PageType), e) == Model.ValueType.Controller)
                {
                    <option value="@e.ToString()" selected>@Enum.GetName(typeof(ValueTypeModel.PageType), e)</option>
                }
                else
                {
                    <option value="@e.ToString()">@Enum.GetName(typeof(ValueTypeModel.PageType), e)</option>
                }
            }
        </select>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In case of edit get and select value from model using `@Model.ModeName` and get complet list from enumeration `Common.Values`

```
<select asp-for="@Model.ModeName" class="form-select" asp-items="Html.GetEnumSelectList<Common.Values>()"></select>
```