# How to add tooltip to enum selection in propertygrid in C#?

Tags: c#, winforms, tooltip, propertygrid

I just found out how to use the basic features of a PropertyGrid and I found that some of my enum constants aren't very self-explanatory. Is it possible that when the user opens the list of all the enum constants that a tooltip will appear for whichever constant he hovers his mouse over?

For example if I have a property in a PropertyGrid called SomeEnum and the values are Enum1, Enum2, Enum3. When the user wants to change the value of the property, he brings down the list and hovers over Enum1, a tooltip will appear saying "This is Enum1" and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would want to override the default convert-to-string functionality of the enum as described in these S.O. posts:

[C# String enums](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/424366/c-string-enums)

[C#: How to use a Type Converter to localize enums](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1117961/c-how-to-use-a-type-converter-to-localize-enums)

or this MSDN article:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.typeconverter%28VS.80%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there's any easy way to do what you're asking with a `PropertyGrid`.  What you really should be doing is to rename your enumeration values to express their purposes more clearly; this has the added benefit of making your source code easier to understand.

If you need to specify additional information regarding a *particular property* that's being set through the `PropertyGrid`, you can do so by tagging it with a `DescriptionAttribute`:

```
[Description("This is my description of this property")]
public int Foo { get; set; }
```

If you're really dead set on keeping your enum values as they are, you could potentially implement a `TypeConverter` and flag each property that uses a particular enum with `TypeConverterAttribute`; this would let you explicitly specify a conversion between the enum values and the text that gets displayed in the `PropertyGrid`.  See [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa302326.aspx) for more details.