# More elegant if statement

Tags: c#, optimization

I'm looking to compare a value against a list and then set another variable based on this comparison.

My list is

```
1 = Red
4 = Blue
13 = Green
```

I could have a series of if statements but with a large list this looks messy

```
if (Type == 1)
{
    Name = "Red";
}
else if (Type == 4)
{
    Name = "Blue";
}
else if (Type == 13)
{
    Name = "Green";
}
```

What's an efficient and tidy way to achieve the same?

Comment: Use [`switch`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/06tc147t(v=vs.120)) instead.

Comment: Do you need to have Type to be an integer? I would recommend an enum. This would also allow to assign the name from the enum value directly.

Comment: Also, suggesting you to create an enum type for these types. it will be more elegant.

Comment: Organize correspondent values in a *dictionary*

Comment: You could also investigate the [EnumConverter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.enumconverter(v=vs.110).aspx) or TypeConverter : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1117961/c-how-to-use-a-type-converter-to-localize-enums

Comment: @ViRuSTriNiTy I think you're taking it too personal. The question's title says 'More elegant', don't you think that the answer you suggested (and which works) is more 'quick and dirty' than elegant (although elegant is really a matter of personal choice)

Comment: @vc74 The irony being, that I like enums and I'd consider using them in conjunction with the answer from Pranay.

Comment: @DavidG Same here. As I commented in Pranay's answer, enum to declare the colors you handle which definitely does not mean the enum has to be in charge of the serialization of such values. I find a dic easier to maintain though, especially if colors are changed regularly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make use of dictionary store your values, it will make clean code with less line of code and readable too

```
Dictionary<int, string> data = new Dictionary<int, string>
{
    { 1, "Red" }, 
    { 4, "Blue" },
    { 13, "Green" }
};

string test;
if (data.TryGetValue(1, out test)) // Returns true.
{
   Console.WriteLine(test); 
}
```

Comment: But this way you always need to get the string representation out of the dictionary first. Using an enum would remove this need.

Comment: @ViRuSTriNiTy How is "getting the string out of the dictionary" any worse then "ToString on an enum value"?

Comment: @ViRuSTriNiTy Yes but with this implementation, you can make the map dynamic and store it in a config file, db... If you want to add a new color with an enum, you have to rebuild / redeploy the app

Comment: @DavidG @vc74 Sure one can nitpick on any solution. I was just pointing out that you should or better need to call `TryGetValue()` to avoid dangers like adding new undefined items to the dictionary for example. With an enum alone you don't have that danger but surely other disadvantages appear.

Comment: @ViRuSTriNiTy I'm not saying your solution is better/worse, as you said each solution has its pros+cons. But to me I seems cleaner to separate the collection of colors you support (possibly in an enum) from the way you serialize/deserialize these colors.

Comment: @Pranay, not a big fan of declaration expressions yet? ;)

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to use switch here:

```
switch (Type)
  {
      case 1:
          Name = "Red";
          break;
      case 4:
          Name = "Blue";
          break;
      case 13:
          Name = "Green";
          break;
  }
```

Comment: This isn't more elegant.

Comment: @ViRuSTriNiTy I'd say it's far better than a bunch of `if` statements.

Comment: @DavidG Although i accept it i will never understand this reasoning. In my eyes using switch is uglifing the code.

Comment: @ViRuSTriNiTy It's probably because of all those `break`s, having a "breakless" switch construct in C# would be quite handy (I don't think I ever needed break in C#)

Comment: @ViRuSTriNiTy I agree that it can get ugly, especially with the `break` statements. However, put this in a utility function and `return` the values instead. That makes for much cleaner code imo.

Answer (score 1):

Use a switch statement insted

```
  switch (Type)
  {
      case 1:
          Name = "Red";
          break;
      case 4:
          Name = "Blue";
          break;
      case 13:
          Name = "Green";
          break;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    class Program
    {
        public enum EnumDisplayStatus
        {
            Red = 1,
            Blue = 2,
            Yellow = 3,
            Orange = 4
        }
        static void Main()
        {
            int value = 3;
            EnumDisplayStatus enumDisplayStatus = (EnumDisplayStatus)value;
            string color = enumDisplayStatus.ToString();
            Console.Write(color);
        }
    }
```

Use enum and get string with this way that I showed.

Comment: The problem with relying on the enum ToString()  method has just been discussed - there are problems if localization is needed & also problems if formatting (eg spaces in colors like "Light Blue"). These can be avoided with providing a [TypeConverter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.typeconverter(v=vs.110).aspx) or [EnumConverter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.enumconverter(v=vs.110).aspx) or simply overriding the ToString method.