# How can I modify the format of a DataGridViewComboBoxColumn?

Tags: c#, enums

I have a similar problem as described by the poster [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/796607/how-do-i-override-tostring-in-c-sharp-enums) where they want a combobox to display the descriptions of the enums and not the ToString of the enum.

I really liked [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/796655/1055723) but I noticed that the `DataGridViewComboBoxColumn` does not have a `Format` or a `FormattingEnabled` attribute.

Can anyone present a workaround to this for me please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to my problem here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/796754/1055723

Answer (score 1):

When I need to assign list of enum values to combobox I usually assign `List <Tuple<Enum,string>>` as DataSource then set DisplayMember ValueMember (winforms), DisplayMemberPath SelectedValuePath (wpf) to Item2 and Item1. Then as value I use SelectedValue instead of SelectedItem.

Comment: I don't believe this shows the descriptions of the enums, rather it shows the enum names instead. This is what I currently have. I want the descriptions of the enums to show up as fields for the combobox. Thank you for your response.

Comment: sorry, there was a glitch in my response text. Each item in list has enum and string that can contain any text that you want.